# Laravel-5 / Sentinel disabling default routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am using Laravel5 with Sentinel and have disabled the default routes within the `sentinel.php` config file:

`'routes_enabled => false'`

I am using the `"rydurham/sentinel": "~2.2"` composer package.

Now I am trying to create my own routes for the authentication system to follow.  I managed to get my own custom login page displaying correctly using the following code:

```
Route::get('login', ['as' => 'sentinel.login', function()
{
    return View::make('Auth.login');
}]);
```

However, i'm having a problem trying to get the route to work when the login form is posted.  Here's my route:

```
Route::post('login', ['as' => 'sentinel.session.store', 'uses' => 'Sentinel\Controllers\SessionController@store', function()
{

}]);
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
ReflectionException in Container.php line 736: Class App\Http\Controllers\Sentinel\Controllers\SessionController does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it by adding a `\` in the route path to Sentinel Controller:

```
Route::post('login', ['as' => 'sentinel.session.store', 'uses' => '\Sentinel\Controllers\SessionController@store', function()
{

}]);
```